# Why would a page not return any xpath?

Tags: php, xpath

I have run across a few internet pages where when I run xpath queries (that WORK in 2 different xpath checker chrome extensions), they don't return on my PHP page that I'm running them from.  I'm wondering if these pages have some type of xpath blocker or something (yes, I'm checking their robots.txt for permission).  Or perhaps some other voodoo?  Thanks for any help you can provide!

Here's 2 (edited to add more) lines from my code:

```
    $c = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $this->getUserAgent());
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);

    // Grab the data.
    $html = curl_exec($c);
    curl_close($c);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHtml($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$jsonScripts = $xpath->query('//script[@type="application/ld+json"]');
if($TEST){echo "there are " . $jsonScripts->length . " JSONs<br>";}
```

And from an internet page that won't return anything

```
<script type="application/ld+json">{"@context":"http:\/\/schema.org\/","@type":"Recipe","name":"Healthy Garlic Scallops Recipe","author":{"@type":"Person","name":"Florentina"},"datePublished":"2015-07-29T22:39:18+00:00","description":"Italian garlic scallops, seared to a golden perfection in a cast iron pan and cooked in healthy clarified butter for the ultimate seafood meal!","image":["https:\/\/ciaoflorentina.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2015\/07\/Garlic-Scallops-Healthy-4.jpg"],"recipeYield":"2","prepTime":"PT5M","cookTime":"PT5M","totalTime":"PT10M","recipeIngredient":["1 lb large scallops","1\/4 c clarified butter ghee","5 cloves garlic (grated)","1  large lemon (zested)","1\/4 c Italian parsley (roughly chopped)","1\/2 tsp sea salt + more to taste","1\/4 tsp peppercorn medley (freshly ground)","1\/4 tsp red pepper flakes","A pinch of sweet paprika","1 tsp extra virgin olive oil"],"recipeInstructions":[{"@type":"HowToStep","text":"Make sure to pat dry the scallops on paper towels very well before cooking."},{"@type":"HowToStep","text":"Heat up a large cast iron skillet on medium flame."},{"@type":"HowToStep","text":"Meanwhile in a medium bowl toss the scallops with a drizzle of olive oil or butter ghee, just enough to coat it all over. Sprinkle them with the sea salt, cracked pepper, red pepper flakes and sweet paprika. Toss to coat gently."},{"@type":"HowToStep","text":"Add a little drizzle of butter ghee to the hot skillet, just enough to coat the bottom. Add the scallops making sure not to overcrowd the pan, and sear for about 2 minutes on each side until nicely golden. ( Use a small spatula to flip them over individually )"},{"@type":"HowToStep","text":"Add the butter ghee to the skillet with the scallops and then add the garlic. Remove from heat and using a spatula push the garlic around to infuse the sauce for about 30 seconds. The heat from the skillet will be enough for the garlic to work its magic into the butter. This is how you avoid that pungent burnt garlicky taste we don\u2019t like."},{"@type":"HowToStep","text":"We are just looking to extract all that sweetness from the garlic, and this is how you do it, without burning."},{"@type":"HowToStep","text":"Squeeze half of the lemon all over the scallops and move the skillet around a little so it combines with the butter. Sprinkle with the minced parsley, lemon zest and a drizzle of extra virgin olive oil. Serve with crusty bread or al dente capellini noodles."}],"recipeCategory":["Main Dishes"],"recipeCuisine":["Italian"],"aggregateRating":{"@type":"AggregateRating","ratingValue":"5","ratingCount":"8"}}</script>
```

Comment: The problem is most likely somewhere in the markup of the HTML files you are parsing. Browsers do a lot to compensate for invalid markup, but PHP DOM requires valid XML. Can you provide a link to one of the pages that isn't working?

Comment: @RobRuchte https://addapinch.com/honey-soy-chicken-recipe/

Comment: That URL is working for me with your code, I get two results,  a "Person" and a "Recipe". The markup in the page is invalid though, if you turn on DOMDocument->validateOnParse you can see what a mess it is. Maybe post more of your code before the XPath query?

Comment: @RobRuchte I added more code.  Please let me know if you see a problem (this is working for 95% of pages, btw...).  Thanks for your help!

Comment: That's really strange. I changed to using your CURL and started receiving garbage from the server, then after a few minutes it began working normally.

Comment: @RobRuchte Yep, that one's working now.  Weird.  I hate it when that happens in programming :|.  Here's another that bombs: https://ciaoflorentina.com/garlic-scallops-recipe-healthy/

Comment: The server seems to be gzipping the output twice. I ran the response through gzdecode and got the expected content and the xpath worked.

Comment: @RobRuchte Thanks for your help!  I appreciate your time.  I think it's clear that it's not an issue with my code and so I'm not going to worry about the pages that won't scrape because they have malformed html (unless you have some savvy workaround--do tell!).  If you'll add an appropriate answer, I'll accept it.  Have a great weekend!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the servers (Nginx) are double-gzipping the response (but only sometimes!?). Your code is good, you could try [gzdecode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gzdecode.php) if you do not get the results you expect. I hacked together this test script to demonstrate.

```
<?php
$url = 'http://ciaoflorentina.com/garlic-scallops-recipe-healthy/';

$c = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko');
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);

// Grab the data.
$html = curl_exec($c);
curl_close($c);

$iterations = 0;
do
{
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    @$dom->loadHTML($html);

    $xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

    $jsonScripts = $xpath->query('//script[@type="application/ld+json"]');
    $nodeCount = $jsonScripts->length;

    echo "there are " . $nodeCount . " JSONs".PHP_EOL;

    if($nodeCount == 0)
    {
        //If garbage is coming from server, it's double encoded!
        $html = gzdecode($html);
    }

    $iterations++;
} while($nodeCount==0 && $iterations < 2);
```